# Java: New line separator inserted in ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, newline

I have the following ArrayList of Strings: A01, A02, A03, B01, B02, B03, C01, C02, C03, D01, D02, D03.
How can I print this ArrayList on several lines, each line when the first character modifies, such as

```
A01, A02, A03
B01, B02, B03
C01, C02, C03
D01, D02, D03
```

My code is as follows:

```
private static List<String> seatsList = new ArrayList<>();
   for (char row = 'A'; row <= 'D'; row++) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            seatsList.add(row + String.format("%02d", i));
        }
    }
```

where "seatsList" contains A01, A02, A03, B01, B02, B03, C01, C02, C03, D01, D02, D03. And I want to print each group starting with different letter on another line.

Comment: For best results on this site and for best benefit to you, why not show your own attempt at solving this in your question?

Comment: You can do this with a for loop. I suggest starting by printing one string per line. Then thinking about how you can modify it to print 3 per line.

Comment: Also, you may want to specify when you need a newline. When the first letter changes? Every three elements? So that it has the same height as width? Something else?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, my code was like this:

```
private String name;
private char lastRow;
private int seatsPerRow;
private static List<String> seatsList = new ArrayList<>();

Cinema (String name, char lastRow, int seatsPerRow) {
    this.name = name;
    this.lastRow = lastRow;
    this.seatsPerRow = seatsPerRow;

    for (char row = 'A'; row <= lastRow; row++) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= seatsPerRow; i++) {
            seatsList.add(row + String.format("%02d", i));
        }
    }
}
```

And the solution that I found to print each row of seats on separate lines was:

```
public void seatsList() {
    for (int i = 0; i <= ((int)lastRow - 65) * seatsPerRow; i += seatsPerRow) {
        System.out.print(seatsList.subList(i, i + seatsPerRow) + "\n");
    }
}
```

I used the subtraction of 65 because 64 is the difference between the numerical value of a char cast to int and the numerical position of that letter in the alphabet. And I subtracted another 1 in order to avoid IndexOutOfBound exception.
For example, char A cast to int is 65 and its position in alphabet is 1. So the difference is 64.